# Yii2 how to anchor the value of the relationship in the GridView

Tags: php, gridview, relationship

I am beginner. I explain the topic:

there is this relationship in the `Ticket` model:

```
public function getTyp()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Typology::className(), [ 'id' =>'typ_id']);
}
```

and in the ticket table there is the typ_id column (it is in relationship with the id of the Typology table).
In the view `views/ticket/index.php` there is `GridView::widget`with these `columns`:

```
  [
     'attribute' => 'typ_id',
     'value' => 'typ.typology' 
  ],
```

I want to anchor the value of the relationship.
I have tried this:

```
  [
     'attribute' => 'typ_id',
     'value' => function ($model) {
               return Html::a (
              'typ.typology',
              '/typology/view?id='.$model->typ_id
               );
      }
  ]
```

but it doesn't work

someone can help me﻿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Html::a()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail) interprets `typ.typology` as raw string. Use `$model` in [value closure](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail) to get necessary property through relation.

Also instead of manually concatenate the url with its parameters, just pass them in array (see [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) to understand how link is constructed).

```
[
    'attribute' => 'typ_id',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Html::a($model->typ->typology, ['/typology/view', 'id' => $model->typ_id]);
    },
],
```

Comment: I have created an other similar question, the problem with queryparms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258210/yii2-activedataprovider-dont-work-after-queryparms-in-action